# From hexadecimal to one's complement in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, ones-complement

Is there an easy way to produce a one's complement in python?

For instance, if you take the hex value `0x9E`, I need to convert it to `0x61`.

I need to swap the binary 1's for 0's and 0's for 1's. It feels like this should be simple.

Answer (score 29):

Just use [the XOR operator `^`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) against 0xFF:

```
>>> hex(0x9E ^ 0xFF)
'0x61'
```

If you need to work with values larger than a byte, you could create the mask from the [`int.bit_length()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) on your value:

```
>>> value = 0x9E
>>> mask = (1 << value.bit_length()) - 1
>>> hex(value ^ mask)
'0x61'
>>> value = 0x9E9E
>>> mask = (1 << value.bit_length()) - 1
>>> hex(value ^ mask)
'0x6161'
```

Comment: OK I'm confused, why is `~x` wrong? It's supposed to be the binary negation operator after all. I can't wrap my mind over the lack of signed/unsigned distinction when binary ops are concerned

Comment: @Kos: `~` literally returns `-(x+1)`, which is great when dealing with signed values. So `~0x9E` is `-159`, or `-0x9f` hex. For unsigned bitwise work, not so great..

Comment: OK I got this, Python's "conceptually infinite string of `1`'s in front of negative numbers" approach has messed with my head. Analogies to C bitwise ops won't work here :(

Comment: @aka.nice: Sure, that works (I used `|` bitwise or accidentally). You still need to create the mask though.

Answer (score 2):

Hah. just found out that python `bin()` return a string!

so we can have some fun at this!

```
for x in numbers: # numbers is a list of int
    b = bin(x)
    #print b # e.g. String 0b1011100101
    b = b.replace('0', 'x')
    b = b.replace('1', '0')
    b = b.replace('x', '1')
    b = b.replace('1b', '0b')
    #print b # String 0b0100011010
    print int(b, 2) # the decimal representation
```

Comment: This just made it to the top five of my most-pragmatic-code list :)