# complement/negate a boolean string in python

Tags: python

I have a list of boolean strings. Each string is of length 6. I need to get the complement of each string. E.g, if the string is "111111", then "000000" is expected. My idea is

```
bin(~int(s,2))[-6:]
```

1. convert it to integer and negate it by treating it as a binary number
2. convert it back to a binary string and use the last 6 characters.

I think it is correct but it is **not readable**. And it only works for strings of **length less than 30**. Is there a **better and general way** to complement a boolean string?

I googled a 3rd party package ["bitstring"](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/bitstring_classes.html). However, it is too much for my code.

Comment: Python is not C, What problem are you trying to solve using this approach?

Comment: "correct but it is not readable" What does that mean O_ó ? The code is hard to understand?

Comment: @FredrikPihl I am using geng (http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/), a subroutine of nauty to generate graphs. The format of the output is a string of characters and each character encodes 6 binary bits.

Comment: This link could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492826/ones-complement-python

Comment: @luk32 Without the explanation of context, I find it confusing myself. Anyway, I should just treat this "complementing" as "replacing" as the two answers suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you basically have a string in which you want to change all the 1s to 0s and vice versa. I think I would forget about the Boolean meaning of the strings and just use maketrans to make a translation table:

```
from string import maketrans

complement_tt = maketrans('01', '10')

s = '001001'
s = s.translate(complement_tt)  # It's now '110110'
```

Comment: Your idea is super clean!

Answer (score 1):

Replace in three steps:

```
>>> s = "111111"
>>> s.replace("1", "x").replace("0", "1").replace("x", "0")
'000000'
```